# How to create instance variables with iterator

Tags: ruby, sinatra, instance-variables

I have a lab through school where I need to create a form that takes in basketball team attributes, team name, coach, point guard etc., and want to know if there is any way to dynamically create instance variables and symbols using an iterator of sorts instead of hard coding them?

Here is the hard-coded version of what I mean:

```
post "/team" do
  @name = params["name"]
  @coach = params["coach"]
  @pg = params["pg"]
  @sg = params["sg"]
  @pf = params["pf"]
  @sf = params["sf"]
  @c = params["c"]
  erb :team
end
```

I want to use something similar to this:

```
post '/team' do
  params.each do |parameter|
    @[parameter] = params["#{parameter}"]
  end
  erb :team
end
```

When I run the above code I receive a unexpected end-of-input syntax error.

Comment: "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)" is worth reading. Also, when asking on SO grammar is important. SO isn't a message board or chat forum, it's more like an online reference book of programming Q&A: think of an encyclopedia, so spelling and capitalization count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`instance_variable_set`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set),
something like this:

```
post '/team' do
  params.each do |key, value|
    self.instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
  end
  erb :team
end
```

Comment: Yakov, thank you so much. This is exactly what i needed and will be sure to use this in future!

Comment: No problem. Just be careful with parameters that came from the outside. Whitelist them or prepare to be used in your application.

Comment: When answering, please describe why the solution is appropriate and should be the selected choice. We're trying to educate, not just answer the immediate problem.